# Can't use pop method on state array in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hey guys I must be missing something small, what I'm trying to do is delete an array item from the state so that react renders the right amount of questions. My "More" button works perfectly, but when I try the "Less" button everything disappears and I get error: questions.map is not a function.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react' 

export default function Truefalse(props) {

    const [questions, setQuestions] =useState([1])




   return (
   <div className=''>
       {questions.map((question)=> {
           return <div style={{width: '200px', height:'200px', color: 'blue', backgroundColor:'blue', margin: '2em'}}></div>
       })}
       <button onClick={()=> setQuestions([...questions, 1])}>More</button>
       <button onClick={()=>setQuestions(questions.pop())}>Less</button>
       <h1>question: {questions.length}</h1>
   </div>
   )
}
```

Comment: It looks like this: [1, 1, 1, 1]. Because each time "more" is clicked it adds a 1 to the array. which is fine because I just need the length of the array. But I can't seem to pop any off.

Comment: questions.pop() will return the item that was removed from the array, not the array with one less item. You should create a callback function that does the pop first, and THEN performs setQuestions(questions).

Answer (score 0):

You've got a couple of issues.

1. [You are directly modifying the state when removing an item](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly)
2. [You aren't using keys when rendering the list of questions](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)

Here is an example showing how to remove the the last item as well as what I mean by using keys when rendering a list. https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-gates-vwv61?file=/src/TrueFalse.jsx

The relevant code is:

```js
const remove = useCallback(() => {
  setQuestions((prev) => {
    // 1. we clone the array by destructuring
    // 2. use pop to remove last item in array
    const next = [...prev];
    next.pop();
    return next;
  });
}, [setQuestions]);

/// ...

{questions.map((question, index) => (
  <div
    key={`${question}-${index}`}
    style={{
      width: "200px",
      height: "200px",
      color: "blue",
      backgroundColor: "blue",
      margin: "2em"
    }}
  >
    {question}
  </div>
))}
```

Notice that our remove function first clones the array and then removes the last item rather than directly modifying the state.

Also see how the questions are rendering with the key prop. In this example I use both the value as well as the index, since using the value alone would result in a non-unique keys.